# How can I use ngettext() of php-gettext when the singular and plural form are the same?

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

I'm using using library [`php-gettext`](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext) to workaround the missing `gettext` extension on Google Cloud AppEngine. When the singular and plural form are the same in English, but different in other languages.

```
ngettext("%d correct", "%d correct", $n)
```

The Spanish translation would be

```
"%d correcto" (singular)
"%d correctos" (plural)
```

indicating the number of correct answers given.

But this gives me an error since the singular `msgid` is exactly the same as the plural `msgid`. Even the function `dngettext()` that allows to add a context to a translation, doesn't do the trick:

```
dngettext("Number of correct answers", "%d correct", "%d correct", $n)
```

It triggers a warning and an error in the `gettext` library:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: -1
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!=' (T_IS_NOT_EQUAL)
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: number
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 4 for gettext_reader::npgettext()
```

I am using the English sentences as `msgid`s and cannot change my whole project now to use cryptic IDs instead, like for example something like

```
ngettext("%d-correct-singular", "%d-correct-plural", $n)
```

What would be the appropriate way of handling identical singular and plural forms in the original language?

Comment: What's the error with the first example? I just tried it and it ran fine (albeit without translation tables)

Answer (score 0):

Just found it is actually a known bug in the gettext library: https://bugs.launchpad.net/php-gettext/+bug/1415873?comments=all

You need to manually fix this bug to be able to use the ngettext function correctly.

This problem has nothing to do with the general gettext extension.